# FCK editor 2.3.2 error in firefox 17 - TypeError: FCKeditorAPI is undefined

Tags: firefox, fckeditor

Hi I have problem with old FCK editor 2.3.2 in new firefox 17, there is js error: "TypeError: FCKeditorAPI is undefined". I have tried solution with FCKeditor_IsCompatibleBrowser return always true, but it doesnt work, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the same problem but found a fix on Bugzilla. See comment 8 and make sure you paste into the correct position within the line. Worked for me.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=814019

Comment: thanks, after all, after debug, just right now we do similar solution.. for firefox 17, IsGecko10 has to be false and IsGecko19 true (our solution is less prettier, but works),
  thanks.
just for fun (we have just packed version of gecko.js :) ):

IsGecko10=((B<20051111)||(/rv:1\.7/.test(s))) && !((B >= 17) && (B < 100));

IsGecko19=/rv:1\.9/.test(s) || ((B >= 17) && (B < 100));

Answer (score 4):

In file **fckeditor\fckeditor_php5.php**, replace `return ($iVersion >= 20030210) ;` to `return true ;`

```js
function FCKeditor_IsCompatibleBrowser()
{
    [...]
    else if ( strpos($sAgent, 'Gecko/') !== false )
    {
        $iVersion = (int)substr($sAgent, strpos($sAgent, 'Gecko/') + 6, 8) ;
        return true ;
        //return ($iVersion >= 20030210) ;

    }
   [...]
}
```

Comment: Yes this, or modified version with complex condition, is necessary part of the solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution is downloading CKEditor http://ckeditor.com/download.

Then, puts the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and the class="ckeditor" in textareas.

Ex :

```
<textarea cols="80" class="ckeditor" id="editeur" name="editeur" rows="10"></textarea>
```

it will works and you will be happy ! :)